# How i can click an image using vba?

Tags: vba

How i can click an image using vba ? This is a download link. I want to save file automatically. HTML code here :

Thank you

```html
<a onclick="location.href='/api/download.aspx?'+pixel.utils.getQueryPath()" href="javascript:;">
    <img src="/images/zip.png" border="0" alt="indir">
   </a>
```

Comment: If by "I want to save file automatically" you mean that the browser should immediately present the user with the save dialog, that can be achieved using setting the `Content-Disposition` header to `attachment` in the code handling the /api/download.aspx request

Answer (score 0):

try to use "onclick"? for example like this:

`For Each ee In ehtml.getElementsByTagName("img")
      If Trim(LCase(ee.src)) = ""/images/zip.png"" Then
         ee.FireEvent ("onclick")
         '''believe got popup for download after click the image
         '''use your code to download from the popup
         Exit For
      End If
 Next ee`

Comment: Thank you for solution. I can't add your code into my module. What is ee = ? ehtml = ?

Comment: sorry about that.. I had going through your website and it seems like you need to find the "iframe" first and then you can find the image by click the button. FYI, the website is had quite sometimes to fully finish loading(including all the background html code). Please put "Sleep" and "Doevents" for your precaution. Anyway, please see the below code in the answer section.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that I modified a bit. The reason why I put "Doevents" and "sleep" is because to make sure the macro is run properly and submit data as the connection here is a bit slow. No harms to add this. Hope can solve your problems :)

```
Dim ee as variant, elt as variant, bool as boolean: bool= False
DoEvents: Sleep 1000

For Each ee In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("a")
If ee.ID = "finansalGit" Then
    ee.Click: DoEvents: Sleep 1000: Exit For
End If
Next

Set HTMLDoc = MyBrowser.document
DoEvents: Sleep 1000
For Each ee In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("iframe")
  If Trim(LCase(ee.ID)) Like "*" & Trim(LCase("externalSite")) & "*" Then
    For Each elt In ee.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
        elt.Click
        '''''or you can used this
        elt.FireEvent ("onclick")

        '''use your code to download from the popup
        bool = True
        Exit For
    Next elt

  End If
   If bool Then
       Exit For
   End If
Next ee
```